# Need more memory for my iPad app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, memory-management

I am working on a mail client on iPad (similar to that of the default app client) and using core data framework as a cache to increase performance . My app uses around 4.5 - 5  MB of heap memory and then it crashes because of memory overflow (detected this using allocation instrument). If I try to reduce memory my performance becomes very slow and sluggish because I am not able to cache my views, data structure (which store folders and all the mails) and tableviews.

I have checked my crashLogs and I see jettisoned written in front of my App which confirms that OS has forcefully closed my App!

I have used instrument to detect these limits. [Please find the attached image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRqmU.png) 
This is a snapshot my recordings just before the app crashes.

I have tested my app on simulator and it stabilizes itself at 6 - 7 MB of heap memory.
Is there any way so that I can ask OS for more memory or avoid crash with a little redesign in my code.

Any suggestions or help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should reuse view, rather than having multiple view to cache the data. Cache the data in memory is OK, but if too much, you have to cache to disk.

Comment: Memory overflow means you have touched unallocated memory (perhaps you have written beyond the end of an allocated block or you have a corrupted pointer). I don't think this is a heap size problem.

Comment: Yes, I am using Core Data to cache to disk. I am not reusing views. But I make sure I release them.

Comment: @wrock , could you please elaborate a little more .

Comment: @wrock Is there any way I could confirm that ..

Comment: To monitor your apps memory usage try using the Activity Monitor instrument. How much memory (total real memory) is you're app using when run on the actual device?

Comment: @KunalBalani I can't really, maybe if you could provide a screenshot of Leaks when it detected the memory overflow.

Comment: @wrock I don't have any memory leaks. I am intentionally keeping all objects alive so that if user is going through several mails and coming back to some previous mail then I dont need to fetch that from the server all over again . I can just display him. I know that's a wrong approach but I am trying to improve my design . I am just looking for an alternative approach that can help me to provide a little more memory because It's the initially UI which takes a lot of memory not my data structure .

Comment: @ade Thanks ... I will surely check that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6-8MB of memory should never be a problem. Likely you are either trashing memory or if you are running a debug version and have Zombies turned on, the default is to never delete the zombies. NSZombiesEnabled=YES and NSDeallocateZombies=NO will appear to leak memory as nothing is ever deleted.